# How to get exact media query value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, media-queries

I have used `$(window).width()` and `$(window).outerWidth()` but both will ignore the scroll bar. So if the scroll bar is 15px width, then `$(window).width()` and `$(window).outerWidth()` will be 755px when media query is 770px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/midana/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Pretty well supported, you can use `matchMedia` <sup>[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)</sup>

```
var mediaQ770 = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 770px)');

mediaQ770.addListener(function(ev) {
    if(ev.matches) {
        console.log("<=770");
    } else {
        console.log(">770");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because CSS is using the device width, and JS the document width.

Here a js function to get the viewport width :

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
```

Comment: This actually doesn't seem to account for scrollbars. At least not in firefox 35.